# How prevent copying web application interface code (HTML+JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-web-api, obfuscation

I'm creating web application that use rest web api (ASP.NET Web Api) for all buisness logic.
Thus web application is only cover for this rest api.

I found no reason to use any platform except simple html files, because:
I have base html page that dynamicaly load all parts of html interface using jquery.get().
And i have client side knockout.js code that interprets json data from web api to rich, fast interface.

I know that there is no way to 100% secure code of my app.

But if malicious user download all HTML files, all CSS files, and all JavaScript files, he can get fully functional platform independed clone of my app. That work with my api or work with mock api. He can change logo and put to web.

I have only one idea for solving this problem:

1. Use google closure compiler for obfuscating and minifying javascript.
2. Obfuscate styles in css and html files.
3. Create new routing system that encript urls to web api for any connection.

   **from:** site.omg/api/employees/1324 **to:** site.omg/api/kghsfjhgsadf
4. also create new routing for html parts.

   **from:** site.omg/main/navigationPart.html **to:** site.omg/asfdsaf

---

There are any "best practies" for prevent copying  code of web app interface?

preffered technologies: .net, java, node.js

Comment: Why to use hours/days to create something which can be hacked in ten minutes?

Answer (score 0):

Everything that can be obfuscated by a process, can be de-obfuscated by another process.

How safe is it? It is not.

*But you have not explained what the threat model is. How can it be misused by understanding the javascript?* Is the problem confidentiality, integrity or identity?

HTTP has something for all of this. Various HTTP-based identity schemes such as OAuth or even basic authentication exists while SSL can provide you with confidentiality and integrity.

Comment: I update my question. First of all I want prevent full copying my interface. Because I use only JavaScript and HTML. Other side I don't want use server side page generation like google templates or asp.net Mvc razor, because all what I need can be done with knockout.js fast and without loading large internet traffic.

Answer (score 0):

I personally find a few solutions for complex (html+css+javascript) obfuscating html apps.

1. [JScrambler](https://jscrambler.com/) Web-Service for protection web and mobile apps with many features (like canvas protection and domain code locks).
2. [Html-muncher](http://htmlmuncher.com/) Free python console utility for code obfuscation.